# Sending HTML table in body of email in Airflow

Tags: python, airflow

We have an html table trying to send in body of email by using below code and code is keep on running but havent received any email

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from smtplib import SMTP
import smtplib
import sys


recipients = ['ravi1234@gmail.com'] 
emaillist = [elem.strip().split(',') for elem in recipients]
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['Subject'] = "Insurance details"
msg['From'] = 'from@domain.com'


html = """\
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    {0}
  </body>
</html>
""".format(df_test.to_html())

part1 = MIMEText(html, 'html')
msg.attach(part1)

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.sendmail(msg['From'], emaillist , msg.as_string())
```

is there any way we can send it through email body having html table

Comment: yes just make sure to add `Content-type=text/html;charset=UTF-8` in the header

Comment: @Souhailhimself .. I added but still facing same issue

Comment: you have to import  `MIMEBase` from `email.mime.base`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this before you send the message:

```
part1 = MIMEText(html,_subtype='html')
```

and remove the `msg.attach(part1)`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply.. Can you suggest me from which airflow model we can get the Dag description which will be displayed in Ui

Comment: @Ravi Sorry but I haven't worked with airflow before but I can help you if you want to send an email using python